# Adding new pages to Menu

Tags: menus

I am new to Wordpress. I am using the free Theme for my blog. I have added Menu as About Us, Contact Us, Groups etc ..

I need to add Static Pages  to About Us, Contact Us etc ..!!

I dont know to How to create and map it to the Menu !!

Comment: How did you add page links to your menu, if those pages **didn't exist in the first place**? What Theme are you using? (Also: if either answer below resolved your issue, please **accept the answer** by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Go into the dashboard and then to the pages menu. Add a page, give it a title of About Us. Do this for as many pages as you need.

Then go to Appearance > Menus

On the right fill in the Menu Name, you can name it anything (i.e. Main Menu, Primary)
Over to the left you should see a box that says Theme location, depending on the theme there may be several drop downs. Pick the first one and select the name you just created on the left. Next scroll down a bit on the left you should see Pages with a list of the pages you created. Click and check the boxes of the ones you want in your menu. They will appear in the right. You can drag and drop these in the order you like. Be sure to save.

Comment: that helps ! Still exploring more into it. Also the link posted by blogjunkie is userfriendly !!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a video that teaches you exactly how to use the menu feature:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9IZb6ygEPU&sns=em

Comment: thank you for the link !! I am new to Wordpress and gradually getting into it. This link is a great kickstart for me to play around with Wordpress !!